# Bitbake: proper way to "patch" a function from a recipe?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

In Yocto build, I need to patch a Python function `do_special_task()` in a recipe under `meta/recipes-devtools`. Naturally, I'm not touching the original `.bb` file, but creating own `.bbappend` in our own layer.

To do this, I copy all the function into `.bbappend`. The diff is just one line, but I have to copy `do_special_task()` in its whole and then change the only line.

Is there a way to better factor the change out? Something like "patch of the `bb` file"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you need to copy/paste the function into a bbappend.

Or, work with whoever wrote the recipe so do_special_task handles both of your needs, possible with a variable to control what it does.

Comment: (note that there is another way but is far too fragile to be suggested)

Comment: Then I'm curious of the fragile way too. If not for production, then at least for learning.

Comment: Use the _remove and _append overrides to edit the source of the function.  It's horrible and hard and prone to break.